# Distance sensors with accuracy of 0.1 mm?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, measurements, sensors, tolerance, industrial-engineering

I am looking for a **sensor** with **0.1 mm** accuracy and a sensing distance of **1-10 cm** for an industrial machine. The machine is used to ensure product quality following the assembly process. It will be operated via a **PLC**. Any suggestions on the **type** of sensor that would best suit these requirements?

Comment: Your question is foul of the [on-topic] guidelines. (Shopping questions aren't allowed.) In any case, you haven't specified a sensing distance, etc. Most of the industrial sensors companies will have laser sensors which might do the job.

Comment: @Transistor i editted it. better now? thanks for the advice. do you think using a laser sensor with PLC a good idea?

Comment: What type of sensor depends a lot on particulars of your system, i mean you could use a time of flight laser,  a infrared distance meter, a lvdt, optical interuption sensor, a camera with a telecentric lens, hell even just a camera with calibration, a optical encoder, a magnetic encoder etc etc.  0.1 mm is nothingin terms of accuracy.

Comment: optical/laser triangulation type distance sensor is another one, more basic / economical than laser TOF or laser interferometer. Don't know if it is good to 100um ... inspection systems using "structured light" and camera sensor are also quite impressive, and fantastic resolution, though not sure if can do absolute distance like TOF or triangulation can and maybe still too $$$

Comment: You would need to specify things like contact or contactless, etc. Because as worded, nothing is stopping me from just moving a touch probe mounted on a encoder-monitored rail right up to the workpiece to measure it. Also, you mention product quality...this doesn't sound like a DISTANCE sensor. This sounds like a dimension measuring tool and you will get different results.

Answer (score 1):

All of the big boys, Keyence, Sick, Omron, ifm, Turck, etc. do a vast range of sensors.

You have the option of using a sensor with digital (on/off) output which you would teach with go / no-go samples. This might be fine if the production value never changes.

The alternative is a sensor with an analog output or one with something like IO-Link which will pass the analog value back in digital form without the intervening analog conversion. This would allow easy pass-band adjustment for various product configurations and also allow you to collect statistics such as mean, standard deviation, etc., which the process controls and quality engineering guys should love.

Call the sales reps and they'll be all over you.